# How do I compute dates of 'suitable viewing nights' when it is 'dark enough' for astronomy, using Wolfram-Language?

Tags: wolfram-language

I'm trying to wrap my head around the Wolfram Language (I have no experience with Mathematica).

I note that 'it' has 'knowledge about' astronomy.  So I am wondering if I can compute the following:

```
tell me the dates and start/finish times of 'dark, socially friendly viewing opportunities during school holidays' where
* 'socially friendly' means between after 10am and before 10:30pm in local time at my vantage point
* it is 'dark' for at least an hour
* where 'dark' means:
  * it's between astronomical sunset and astronomical dawn
  * the moon is either not risen, or less than 15% of its face is lit
* 'school holidays' means school holidays in NSW, Australia, in 2019 (which Wolfram Alpha doesn't 'implicitly know')

put such dates and times as events into my Google Calendar somehow :-)
```

Solving this toy problem would help me appreciate the 'approach' to take to solving problems on this platform, and it seems to cater to the strengths of the Wolfram system.  Plus it would save me an hour or two each year looking stuff up :-)

How would I approach this in a Wolfram-Language 'program' (equation?) ?  Can I do this in Wolfram-Alpha or do I need to get the Engine?

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer to your question. Just a starting point.

```
tz = Entity["TimeZone", "Australia/Sydney"];
date = DateObject[{2019, 07, 14}, TimeZone -> tz];

Sunrise[Entity["City", {"Sydney", "NewSouthWales", "Australia"}], date, TimeZone -> tz]
```

[image]

Similarly for `Sunset`.

```
sunset = Sunset[
  Entity["City", {"Sydney", "NewSouthWales", "Australia"}], 
  DateObject[{2019, 07, 14}, TimeZone -> tz], TimeZone -> tz]
```

You can add/subtract 2 or 3 hours from the result to get the 'astronomical' value.

Moon phase

```
MoonPhase[date]
(* 0.8913 *)

MoonPhase[date, "Name"]["Name"]
(* waxing gibbous moon *)
```

Position of Moon at sunset

```
MoonPosition[Entity["City", {"Sydney", "NewSouthWales", "Australia"}], sunset]
(* {98.67\[Degree],25.03\[Degree]} *)
```

Take a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n4DIkhZ327Y) video for an overview of astronomical and space related entity data in WL.